# Hadoop single node configuration: Allocation memory error during map reduce

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce, vagrant

I'm trying to setup hadoop single node (v2.4.0) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-29-generic x86_64) (I'm using vagrant and puppet for all configuration).
Namenode was formatted and hadoop services started using start-dfs.sh.
Files used for configure hadoop are [here](http://goo.gl/IgP6fX) and virtual machine reserve 4Gb of memory.
When I run example map reduce using command:

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.0.jar grep indput output 'dfs[a-z]+'
```

I receive follow error:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
>   os::commit_memory(0x00000000e0d3e000, 104861696, 0) failed;
>   error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

This is dump of map reduce output:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.0.jar grep indput output 'dfs[a-z]+'
14/06/28 17:19:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/06/28 17:19:11 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
14/06/28 17:19:11 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
14/06/28 17:19:11 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
14/06/28 17:19:11 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 25
14/06/28 17:19:12 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:25
14/06/28 17:19:12 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local41566469_0001
14/06/28 17:19:12 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/vagrant41566469/.staging/job_local41566469_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/06/28 17:19:12 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/vagrant41566469/.staging/job_local41566469_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
14/06/28 17:19:13 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/localRunner/vagrant/job_local41566469_0001/job_local41566469_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/06/28 17:19:13 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/usr/local/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/localRunner/vagrant/job_local41566469_0001/job_local41566469_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
14/06/28 17:19:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
14/06/28 17:19:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local41566469_0001
14/06/28 17:19:13 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
14/06/28 17:19:13 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
14/06/28 17:19:13 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
14/06/28 17:19:13 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local41566469_0001_m_000000_0
14/06/28 17:19:13 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
14/06/28 17:19:13 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/vagrant/indput/log4j.properties:0+11169
14/06/28 17:19:13 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000e0dad000, 104861696, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 104861696 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/hs_err_pid2828.log
```

How I can solve this issue? do I missing set some configuration properties?

Thanks

Bye

Gianluca

Comment: what is the size of the data you are using? can you try to check the mem size that the process is using?

Comment: I used as input sample etc/hadoop config files so some megabytes. how can check mem size (sorry but I'm not an linux expert;))?

Comment: You should run something like `ps aux | grep hadoop` per example to see the real command hadoop had launched or use a tool like `htop`. PS: The link you gave is dead

Comment: Hi, thanks @eliasah for your suggestion! The problem was an error in vagrant file configuration causing not set reserved memory of virtual machine: fixing it, map reduce completed correctly. Thanks for signal broken link: now should be work.

Comment: @John, answers belong in the answers, not in the question. You can post an answer as a community wiki if you wish. But please never add "solved" to a question title.

Comment: @gunr2171. Apologies. This came up in the edit queue yesterday and the OP had stated that they had solved it. Won't do it again.